# Pass multiple string values as parameter from server side to javascript function

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

Can't send multiple string value as parameter to javascript function

My server side coding looks like :

_

```
json += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='chkBoxHelp' onclick='chkbox('" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "','" + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "');'";
```

And my client side coding looks like :

```
function chkbox(id,name) {
alert(id,name);
}
```

Comment: I've added the missing `";` to the end of your statement, since it isn't the problem but was incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you've quoted your attribute value with `'`, it ends at the first `'` inside it.

Instead, use `"`:

```
json += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='chkBoxHelp' onclick='chkbox(\"" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "\",\"" + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "\");'";
// -----------------------------------------------------------------^^--------------------------------^^-^^--------------------------------^^
```

Or, of course, don't use inline `onxyz`-attribute-style handlers at all, as they have several issues, not least that functions like your `chkBoxHelp` have to be globals.

For instance, you might store the arguments as `data-*` values:

```
json += "<td><input type='checkbox' id='chkBoxHelp' data-id='" + dt.Rows[i][1].ToString() + "' data-name='" + dt.Rows[i][2].ToString() + "'";
// -------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...and use modern event handling (`addEventListener`, etc.) to hook up the function, and have the function retrieve the values from the element.